# linking with GCC ld returns 1

Tags: gcc, assembly, linker, ld

I'm trying to create exe out of obj file, that was created by nasm from this code:

```
    global _main
SECTION .data
msg db "Hello World...$"
SECTION .text

_main:

mov edx,msg
mov ah,09
int 21h
exit:
mov ah,4ch
mov al,00
int 21h
```

> file not recognized: File format not recognized
>   collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Show your `nasm` command. And why can't you use `as`  & `ld` from [binutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/) ?

Comment: nasm HelloWorld.asm -o HelloWorld.obj, and what do you mean?

Comment: I probably can, but how?

Comment: Start by reading documentations and tutorials

Comment: I really tried that, but can you stick to my question- why isnt my code working?

Comment: You're not telling Nasm to produce an output format that ld recognizes. The `-o` switch tells Nasm to name the file the file that, but Nasm defaults to a flat binary file. Use the '-f' switch to control the output format. You probably want `-f obj` for this - what you've got there appears to be for DOS... or possibly DJGPP "extended dos". If what you've got is ld for DJGPP, `-f coff` should work. Otherwise - ld for MinGW or so - you'll need different code, and `-f win32`

Comment: shouldn't it work for windows too?

Comment: and I tried what you said with -f obj, and I got the same problem.